# run.sh file execution: cannot open the shared object file (dependence for the executable)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, shared-libraries

Here is a simple run.sh file:

```
  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/builds/linux_x86_64_centos/bin64
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/builds/linux_x86_64_centos/bin64
  LD_LIBRARY64_PATH=/home/builds/linux_x86_64_centos/bin64
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64=/home/builds/linux_x86_64_centos/bin64
  LD_LIBRARY32_PATH=/home/builds/linux_x86_64_centos/bin64
  SHLIB_PATH=/home/builds/linux_x86_64_centos/bin64
  EAI_COMLIB_PATH=/home/builds/linux_x86_64_centos/bin64
  LIBPATH=/home/builds/linux_x86_64_centos/bin64

echo "Executing: Tester ./default.xml"
./Tester ./default.xml
```

The "Tester" in the run.sh file is an excutable, the macros (for example: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH) are environment variables (paths) will be used when running the "Tester"

When I type run.sh in the shell, it shows: ./Tester: error while loading shared libraries: lib910.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Actually, the "Tester", run.sh and the lib910.so is in the same path: /home/builds/linux_x86_64_centos/bin64

I have double checked that the path is correct. not sure why the "Tester " cannot find the lib910.so file.

I am not so familiar with linux. not sure if the environment variables are also used elsewhere after calling the run.sh. Thus, I tried to add `export` like this:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/builds/linux_x86_64_centos/bin64
```

But the problem still exists.

Comment: You have to `export` the variables if you want to make them available to the program.

Comment: Thanks, seems the variables are not defined in this run.sh file. Seems they are defined in some other .sh files called before the run.sh

Comment: Please avoid making up code and claiming you run it. Instead, make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post about that instead.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks for reminding. I am not making up the code. This is a very big program and there are many .sh files.

Comment: Your question only has "a simple run.sh" file. If that file is enough to reproduce the problem, great! If it's just code you made up to try to illustrate what you think is happening, please avoid that.

Comment: Thanks! I think my previous statement is not accurate. This is Tester executable is generated by a big program. But in that folder, only limited .so files and the process is only: type run.sh in the shell, and the run.sh call Tester. Right now I added `export` in the environment variable settings (such as: `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/builds/linux_x86_64_centos/bin64`), but the problem still exists

Comment: Are you sure you're running the right script? `run.sh` is normally not sufficient to run a script in the current directory

Comment: @thatotherguy I think I am running the right script. Moreover, I am running sun.sh itself instead of using run.sh to run other scripts. Thanks